# Change variable of a class with callback that isn't called by the class itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback

There is an external API method that take a callback function.
The callback's arguments is predefined so I can't change.

```
class APIUtil:
    def __init__(self, update):
        self.itemName = "awesomeItem"
        self.update = update

    def change_value(self):
        self.update(self)

def callback_update(self):
    pass

class UserClass:
    name = ''
    util = APIUtil(update=callback_update)
```

I want to set the variable name of UserClass with the itemName of the APIUtil when callback_update is called but I don't know how to do this because I don't have acess to the UserClass instance in this callback.

I thought of something like closures but it seems to work only with nested functions

```
class UserClass:
    name = ''

    def callback_update(self):
        nonlocal name
        name = self.itemName

    util = APIUtil(update=callback_update)
```

> SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'name' found